# Read from text file using TextFieldParser

Tags: vb.net, textfieldparser

When using TextFieldParser to read a text file of fixed field width (3 fields of 17, 90 and 120 characters, i.e. 227 characters), I get an error as soon as I leave my last text box empty (TextBox4 ).
This is happening, it seems to me, because the field length is shorter than expected.

```
 Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
       TextFieldParser(OuvrirFichier, Encoding.UTF8)

                Reader.TextFieldType =
           Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
                Reader.SetFieldWidths(227)
                Dim currentRow As String()
                While Not Reader.EndOfData
                    Try
                        currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
                        Dim currentField As String
                        For Each currentField In currentRow
                            TextBox2.Text = currentField.Substring(0, 17)
                            TextBox1.Text = currentField.Substring(17, 90)
                            TextBox4.Text = currentField.Substring(107) ', 120))
                            Dim node As TreeNode = Me.TreeView1.Nodes(0)
                            TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(TextBox1.Text))
                            ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
                        Next
                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                        MsgBox("La ligne " & ex.Message &
                    " n'est pas valide et sera ignorée.")
                    End Try
                End While
            End Using
```

[image]

'Save

```
Dim fileName As String = OuvrirFichier
                Dim bt As New article With {
                        .Title = TextBox2.Text,
                        .Name = TextBox1.Text,
                        .Charge = TextBox4.Text
                }

                Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append)
                    Using writer As New StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8)
                        If fs.Length > 0 Then writer.WriteLine()
                        writer.Write($"{bt.Title,-17}{bt.Name,-90}{bt.Charge,-120}")
                    End Using
                End Using
```

Comment: `SetFieldWidths()` should be set to the length of your Fields, not the overall length. You need to pass an array of Integers to the method. Then `ReadFields()` will return the Fields' values (note that this method return an array of strings). -- You should also get a `MalformedLineException` if the Fields don't match the parameters specified.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. It's fair but I did it and it still doesn't work! I will nevertheless place my field lengths (3) as parameters of SetFieldWidths.

Comment: Aren't the Fields' widths `17, 90, 120`? + Have you checked the content of the file that's failing? ++ Where's the code where you tried that?

Comment: Yes these are the three field values. The file does not fail, the error is still the same as in the screenshot above. The code is that of saving the data in a text file. I attach it in the post.

Comment: Well, then pass these fixed widths to `SetFieldWidths()` and read the values from the array of strings that `ReadFields()` returns. No loops, no `Substring()`. -- You still haven't said whether the file that's failing matches the expected format (all lines of it).

Comment: The expected format of the file is correct!

Comment: I've just tested the code used to write the data (now that you have shown how the data is saved) and using the method described (setting `Reader.SetFieldWidths({17, 90, 120})`) doesn't produce any exception, even when blank lines are inserted in the file (in any position). -- Do you really need to write the Fields like that? Since you're storing data coming from a class, why don't you serialize to JSON instead? One line of code to serialize all, one line to deserialize all.

Comment: Thanks Jimi, now I think I know why it works for you and not for me. Because for the moment I have only used three variables of a structure which includes about twenty!